# How to track down where NUnit is hanging?

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, bamboo

We have a Bamboo build server, and a build project that is configured to run a couple thousand integration tests, which takes upwards of 20 minutes per build, but it's a price worth paying for the security of having a solid suite of integration tests.  Project is in C#/ASP.NET.

The problem is, the NUnit step frequently hangs.  Doesn't fail, doesn't crash... but it simply stops working, and can remain in this state for days until someone notices, stops the build and restarts it.  Which of course leaves us with a huge backlog of other builds that were in the queue.

This behavior is completely inconsistent.  I'd estimate it works about 50% of the time.  We have 2 build agents on separate machines, and each of these is equally affected by hanging builds.

Is there any way of getting NUnit to log its progress through the integration tests, so we can at least get an idea if there's one test that is regularly causing the build to hang?  Or any other ideas how we could diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any parameterized tests?

Comment: @Valentin: If by that you mean tests decorated with `[TestCase(param1, param2)]`, then yes.

Comment: Can you remote debug into the build machine attaching to the nunit agent process to see where your tests are hung?

Comment: Another option is to run NUnit with the --labels=All command line to output the tests that are being run. Be aware though, at least in NUnit 3, the label  is output at the end of the run, so your hang will be in the next test.

Comment: I think @rprouse meant to say that the labels are output at the end of **each test** rather than the end of the run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nunit v2.0.50727

run with command line parameter /labels
This gives the full name of every test as it is run.